# ImportError: cannot import name 'AlignDlib'

Tags: python-3.x

I have installed openface in my windows machine by following below steps.

Downloaded openface from this inline path : https://github.com/
cmusatyalab/openface

```
cd openface
python setup.py install

--------------------
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3>python.exe openface/setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
copying openface\__init__.py -> build\lib\openface
running install_lib
copying build\lib\openface\__init__.py -> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openface
byte-compiling C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openface\__init__.py to __init__.cpython-36.pyc
running install_egg_info
Removing C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openface-0.2.1-py3.6.egg-info
Writing C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openface-0.2.1-py3.6.egg-info
```

After installation when I tried to access AlignDlib method, I'm getting error -

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'AlignDlib'
```

Appreciate your help, If somebody can help me on how to resolve this error.

Thanks
Bhajesh

Comment: Did you mean to do `from openface import AlignDlib`?

Comment: Can you post the code you are executing?

Comment: Yes, not able to import AlignDlib.

Comment: I'm trying to import AlignDlib from openface.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the issue.

Even  after running the python setup.py install, All the files are not copied into the python path directory.

I found some of the files are missing. Hence I manually copied all those files which are missing and AlignDlib was one of the them in that.

Thanks,