# Jupiter notebook error 'NameError: name 'AlignDlib' is not defined'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-3.7

NameError: name 'AlignDlib' is not defined

I am following this website for open face https://mc.ai/face-recognition-using-openface/
and it instructs me to input the code shown below. It seems the only prerequisite is to have dlib and openCV installed which I do.

## import image

```
img = cv2.imread("001_03.jpg")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

## align face

```
alignment = AlignDlib('landmarks.dat')
face = alignment.getLargestFaceBoundingBox(img)
x = face.left()
y = face.top()
w = face.width()
h = face.height()
```

I expected an output of the face isolated in the image with landmark points on the face (when more code in inputted when this error is corrected). Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name 'AlignDlib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604607/importerror-cannot-import-name-aligndlib)

Comment: Did you import `AlignDlib` before using it?

Comment: import AlignDlib leads to a 'no module found' error. I thought it would have been imported when I imported dlib? (sorry I am new here)